# Without the Axiom of Choice, must two nonempty sets have a surjection between them?

Tags: functions, set-theory, relations, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty sets. Can we show, without using the Axiom of Choice, that there must either be a surjection $A\to B$ or $B\to A$?

With Choice we can do this by using Zorn to obtain a maximal injective partial function $A\to B$, and then extending it to a surjection in one direction or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot show this. For instance, it is consistent to have infinite Dedekind-finite sets whose power set is still Dedekind-finite. Now, if there is a surjection from $A$ to $\omega$, then there is an injection from $\omega$ (indeed, from $\mathcal P(\omega)$) to $\mathcal P(A)$, so $\mathcal P(A)$ is Dedekind-infinite.

Thus, if $\mathcal P(X)$ is infinite Dedekind-finite, then $X$ and $\omega$ are two non-empty sets with no bijections in either direction.

---

More generally, suppose that $X$ is not well-orderable, and let $\Theta$ be the first non-zero ordinal that $X$ does not surject onto. $\Theta$ clearly exists, since if $f:X\to\alpha$ is onto, then there is a partition of $X$ in type $\alpha$. The collection of partitions of $X$ is a set, and for any partition, there are only set-many orders we can put on its classes, so there are only set-many ordinals that work as $\alpha$.

Ok. Clearly, $\Theta$ does not surject into $X$, or $X$ would be well-orderable, since a subset of $\Theta$ would be in bijection with $X$ (by picking least representatives from each preimage). So $X$ and $\Theta$ are an example.

Comment: You answered this, I answered the duplicate, and we both answered the duplicate of the duplicate. The circle is complete.

Comment: @Asaf Hehe. Figures...

Comment: From you I would have expected not to use $\Theta$ "just like that", by the way. What's wrong with $\aleph^*$?

Comment: There was a convoluted reason: I used $\Theta$ because I wanted people to think of $\mathbb R$ under determinacy, where we have no infinite Dedekind-finite sets.

Comment: Anyway, you should probably close this so we get the appropriate links.

Comment: I already have? Before even posting my first comment.

Comment: Hmm... The way these windows refresh is not optimal. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The original Cohen model for ZF + $\neg$AC gives a counterexample. Cohen adjoins a family $F$ of reals such that very little structure exists on $F$; in particular, it's not hard to show that whenever $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that both $F_{<r}$ and $F_{>r}$ are infinite, then there is no surjection from $F_{<r}$ to $F_{>r}$ or from $F_{>r}$ to $F_{<r}$.

- Of course, when I say "not hard to show" that's relative: we need to already understand the construction Cohen gives, [which is quite complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)). However, once its basic properties are developed the statement above is fairly immediate.

Incidentally, this example does not fall into the category Andres mentioned: while $F$ is Dedekind-finite, its powerset is not: the family $$\{F_{<q}:q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$ can be ordered via your favorite well-ordering of $\mathbb{Q}$, and this yields an embedding of $\omega$ into $\mathcal{P}(F)$.

Comment: Doesn't any model of non-AC give an easy counterexample due to Lindenbaum's theorem? You know, like discussed on the duplicate? :)