# Is it possible for there to not exist surjection from sets $X$ to $Y$ when there is also no surjection from $Y$ to $X$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is it possible for there to not exist surjection from sets $X$ to $Y$ when there is also no surjection from $Y$ to $X$? I am strongly included to say no, as the former seems to imply that $|X| < |Y|$ whereas the latter implies the opposite- however, we made assumptions that there exists a mapping which is "one-to-one" enough and doesn't go to the same thing every time when concluding this (which seems a fair assumption, but which I can't formally justify) and if $X$ and $Y$ were infinite sets, perhaps these rules break down.

Comment: If $A \subset B$ (a propery one) then crearly there isnt a surjection from $A$ to $B$. On the other hand, we can define $f: B \rightarrow A$ as $f(x) = x$ if $x \in A$ and $f(x)=a$ for a constant element $a \in A$.

More simple, $f$ is the identity when restringed to $A$ and in map $B \backslash A$ to some element $a \in A$.

Comment: If you work in ZFC then the answer is: no, because any two sets are comparable in cardinality and you cannot have $|X|<|Y|<|X|$. I don't know what the situation is in ZF

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari first of all: of course there can be a surjection $A\to B$ even if $A\subset B$. You will always find such $A$ when $B$ is infinite. In fact it can be treated as definition of infinity. More importantly: OP is not assuming $X\subset Y$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that question depends on the kind of set theory you are working with. The most common nowadays is ZF (and its variations), which stands for [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

Now, in this set theory, it indeed is possible to have [two sets without surjection between them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948710/without-the-axiom-of-choice-must-two-nonempty-sets-have-a-surjection-between-th). Yes, counterintuitive.

But it is also typical to consider ZFC, which is the ZF set theory together with [the Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). This axiom changes everything, in some sense the theory is a lot more restrictive. The following statements are provable within ZFC:

1. For any two sets $X$ and $Y$ at least one of the following is true: $|X|\leq |Y|$ or $|Y|\leq |X|$. Or in other words: [any two sets are comparable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268942/for-any-two-sets-a-b-a-leqb-or-b-leqa), which is also known as the Principle of Cardinal Comparability. By the way, it is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.
2. $|X|\leq |Y|$ if and only if there is surjection $Y\to X$. This statement is known as the Principle of Partition and [you can find the proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192460/there-exists-an-injection-from-x-to-y-if-and-only-if-there-exists-a-surjecti). As far as I understand it is still an open question whether the Principle of Partition implies the Axiom of Choice, [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905652/millers-construction-partition-principle-and-failure-of-axiom-of-choice).

which together answer your question.

> I am strongly included to say no, as the former seems to imply that $|X| < |Y|$

Only under the Axiom of Choice. So as you can see, the devil is in the details...